# How to Toggle between adding and removing Ajax text

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am a programming student, I have worked out this programming that adds in rain.text from the server which says 'the rain in spain stays mainly on the plain'. But I'd like the program to remove rain text when the user clicks the button again, then add rain.txt in again if the user clicks the button once more. Any help with how to approach this please?

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

#hidereveal
{
margin:auto;
width:90%;
height:auto;
border: 1px black solid;
text-align:center;
}

p
{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hidereveal">

<p>this is a test, when you click the button and ajax will add in more data 
from the server<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Click to read 
more</button></p>


</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML += this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "rain.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
 }
</script>

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Hey, do you require the ajax call everytime the button is pressed or does the data remain the same everytime ? In which case using something to store the data locally the first time is a better idea

Comment: Hi, I'd like the button to either ajax call rain.txt or remove rain.txt (you can't see rain.txt but all it says is 'the rain in spain stays mainly on the plain') - so each hit of the button either calls or deletes rain.txt in alternate order, just no idea how to approach this so far.

Comment: By delete do you mean that you would like to remove it from your backend or just the current page ?

Comment: Just the current page and then reload it from the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace this code

```
document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML += this.responseText;
```

with this code

```
let elem = document.getElementById("hidereveal")
elem.innerHTML !== '' ? elem.innerHTML = '' : elem.innerHTML += elem.innerHTML
```

---

```html
<html>
<head>

<style>

#hidereveal
{
margin:auto;
width:90%;
height:auto;
border: 1px black solid;
text-align:center;
}

p
{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hidereveal">

<p>this is a test, when you click the button and ajax will add in more data 
from the server<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Click to read 
more</button></p>


</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
let elem = document.getElementById("hidereveal");
elem.innerHTML !== '' ? elem.innerHTML = '' : elem.innerHTML += elem.innerHTML
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "rain.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
 }
</script>

</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, here's the version I worked out after some trial and error!Bascially a function to show more or less text using Ajax and without reloading the page, works fine.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

#hidereveal
{
margin:auto;
width:90%;
height:auto;
border: 1px black solid;
text-align:center;
}

p
{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hidereveal">

<p>This is a test, when you click the button, ajax will add in more data 
from the server. <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Read more or less! 
</button></p>
<div id="xml"></div>

</div>

<script>



function loadDoc() {
if(document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML == ''){

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML += this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "rain.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}
else 
{
document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML="";  
}



}

</script>


</body>
```